# Initialization of struct pointer containing a struct pointer of same type

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, c++17

I am trying to understand how the initialization of a pointer to a struct object (which contains a pointer to a struct of the same type) occurs. e.g I have a `struct`:

```cpp
struct node {
    node *next;
  };
```

Suppose I have the starting address of a pool of memory i.e pool is a pointer to the starting location. (For sake of argument lets say the starting memory is `1001`.)

```cpp
char* pool[65536];
```

Now I declare a pointer of type `node` and assign it the starting memory through `reinterpret_cast`.

```cpp
node* a =reinterpret_cast<node *>(pool);
```

Currently `a` points to the memory `1001`. Now I declare another pointer

```cpp
node* b;
b=a;
```

Now what happens is that `b` points to the same address as `a` i.e `1001`. The pointer `b->next` points to some random location which is expected but the address of the pointer `b->next` is the same as the address to which `b` is pointing i.e `1001`. i.e

```
&b->next = b
```

I don't understand why the address of `b->next` is the same as the one to which pointer `b` is pointing? According to my understanding `b->next` should be located where `b` is located.

P.S: I have tried to find how this happens but could not find the relevant documentation. If this type of question is already answered in some documentation or another question, please do provide a link.

P.P.S: After discussing this problem further with my colleague, I found out that `b` is a pointer and not an object. It is pointing to a location (i.e `1001`) where according to `b` a node object exists which contains the pointer `next` and therefore the address of `b->next` (`&b->next`) is the same as the location to which `b` is pointing.

[image]

Comment: `node* a =1001;` won't compile.

Comment: Since you used the C++17 tag specifically, I removed the C tag. C and C++ are different languages and the answer might depend on that. If you wanted to ask about C, please change the C++ tags to a C tag.

Comment: Why should the address of `b->next` be different from the one to which `b` is pointing? Where else would `b->next` be located, in your opinion? The fact that both are of type `node*` is irrelevant. Consider: `struct S {int n;}; S s; std::cout << ( (void*)&s == (void*)&s.n );` This will print `1`

Comment: Trying random things is not a good way to learn C++.

Comment: Pointer are hard and a long topic. I suggest going through the cahpter(s) of a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on pointers and then see if that answers your question.  Another bit of info that is needed is that for standard layout types (what node is) the address of the class is the same as the address of it's first member.

Answer (score 2):

Lets take the basic premises, but with a valid example instead:

```
node* a = new node;
node* b = a;
```

Now both `a` and `b` are pointing to the very same object, the very same location in memory.

Somewhat graphically it would look like this:

```
+---+
| a | --\
+---+    \     +-----------------+
          >--> | the node object |
+---+    /     +-----------------+
| b | --/
+---+
```

Because both `a` and `b` are pointing to the exact same object, then it follows that `a->next` and `b->next` must be exactly the same. You could verify it by printing `&a->next` and `&b->next`.

The only way that the (currently indeterminate) value of `a->next` and `b->next` could appear to differ is because of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). First of all because `a->next` (and therefore `b->next`) is indeterminate, using its value in any way except to initialize it leads to UB. Secondly, if you don't initialize `a` or `b` in a correct way (for example you really initialize it as in your question) then you also have UB when you dereference `a` or `b`.

Comment: It's rationnal: if a = b, f(a) = f(b).

Comment: "could differ" -> "could appear to differ"

Answer (score 1):

> Lets say I declare a pointer of type node and assign it some starting memory (e.g 1001)

For the sake of argument, I'm going to pretend that this code compiles, that you can directly assign an arbitrary integer to a pointer without a `reinterpret_cast`.

`a` now is what C++ calls an "invalid pointer". It is a pointer, but it doesn't point to anything.

> Now what happens is that "b" points to the same address as "a" i.e 1001.

That is correct. `b` is now as invalid as `a`.

> The pointer "b->next"

Nope. If you dereference an invalid pointer, you get undefined behavior. `b` does not actually point to a `node` object, so there is no `b->next` pointer. So talking about the value of a `b->next` pointer that doesn't exist is meaningless.

> the address of the pointer "b->next" is the same as the address to which b is pointing i.e 1001.

It sounds like what you're actually talking about is the layout of the struct `node`. The fact that, given some object of type `node`, the address of that object and the address of its first data member will be the same. Since `node` is standard layout, that will be true.

But it's important to note that the address of the first data member is not the address that `next` *points to*. It is the address of `next` *itself*. A pointeris an object, just like any other object, so it has storage in memory. Therefore, you can get a pointer *to a pointer*. It is that pointer to the `next` pointer which will have the same address as the `node` object it lives within, not the *value* of the `next` pointer itself.

That is, in a hypothetically valid example, the address of `b` and `&b->next` would be the same.

Answer (score -1):

It's a requirement of C++ (modulo memory padding): the first member of a structure is located to the same address as the structure itself.

For the comparison,
you can see it as an array, in the string

`abcd`

(The `a` is taken for practical purpose, it is not the same as the `a` in your question)

The `a`, is located to the same location as the string `abcd`.
The string is your structure, and each letter is a field. `a` can be `node::next`. The term "pointing to a structure" is a synonym for "pointing to the first byte of the given structure".

For example, if the question is, where is the string `abcd` located in this sequence :

`1234abcd56789`

You would say `4` because it's where the *first element* of the string is. It's juste the same, in most cases, with C++. And `a` is also located in the position `4`.

Note: As mentioned by NathanOlivier, this is only valid for **standard layout types**.

Comment: *the first member of a structure points in the same address than the structure itself.* This is only guaranteed for standard layout types.